# Google Play Store downloads won't start

Tags: google-play-store, downloading, google-play-services, google-apps, download-manager

I ran a speed test and I'm getting a full 4Mb/s. However, when trying to download an app, it's stuck on the indeterminate progress"Downloading" bar. 20 mins later it gives me an error saying it couldn't be installed. It's not just one app, it's EVERYTHING I try to download.

[image]

Comment: Under settings > apps > show System apps > you will find download manager > storage > clear data and cache , reboot and try again. May fix

Comment: Just tried, didn't work

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yes, I did reboot

Comment: Hmm.. clearing data /cache of Google play store and framework?

Comment: Are you using a package disabler of some sort? Make sure you are not freezing components used by Playstore i.e download manager, google play services etc. Also try removing and re adding Google account. Another good fix is unistaling Playstore updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Ensure components used by Playstore are not disabled

   - Check if download manager, Google play services or Google services framework is not disabled or frozen by package disabler apps.
   - Freezing/ or disabling such can result in failed downloads.
   - Re-enable them as necessary

---

2. Removing and re-adding Google account

   - Sometimes perfoming this this step acts as a way of "refreshing" Google Apps including Playstore and may fix failed downloads.

---

3. Uninstalling Playstore updates.

   - You can try removing Playstore updates and then update to latest version which can solve the issue, as a certain version can have bugs. Do this:

> Reinstall Play Store updates
>
> 1. Open your device's main Settings app.
> 2. Touch Apps or Application manager (depending on your device, this may be different).
> 3. Touch Google Play Store > Uninstall updates .
> 4. When prompted to change the Play Store app back to the factory version, touch OK.
> 5. Open the Google Play Store app Google Play .
> 6. Go back to your device's home screen. As long as you have a strong Internet connection (Wi-Fi or mobile data), your Play Store app will
>      update to the latest version within a few minutes.

---

4. Clearing Playstore data

   - You can restore Google Playstore to default by clearing its data, which can hopefully solve the issue of failed downloadsn

> Clear cache and data
>
> 1. Open your device's main Settings app.
> 2. Touch Apps or Application manager (depending on your device, this may be different).
> 3. Touch Google Play Store > Clear cache > Clear data .

---

Source: Google Playstore Help - [Play Store won't load or download apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/6241347?hl=en#ts=6241336%2C6241346%2C6241382%2C6241389%2C6241402)