# Google Play store GPS test app download fails, Google Maps work fine on 3G, what's wrong?

Tags: google-play-store

re.:
Google Play store GPS test app download fails, Google Maps work fine on 3G, what's wrong ?

I can open Google Play store app on my Android 5.0 Medion smartphone
but can't install any application, since waiting, waiting.

Google Maps work fine, so Internet is provided by my operator via 3G plan.

How to know what's wrong with Google Play store.

I have activated email account with gmail, as required.

If you know alternative download website for .apk,
let me know

All I need to do is to test GPS in my phone via GPS test app.

Let me know how to fix the problem.

thank you

BTW1
I don't have on-line payment system activated, since I am interested in free app only.

Comment: ok, installed GPS Test app from
https://apkpure.com/gps-test/com.chartcross.gpstest

so the problem is with Google Play store

let me know your opinion

Comment: ok, got 3D fix  at 7m accuracy at my window, so app is ok and my GPS is operational but how to install app via Google store ?

Comment: Waiting for download
waiting for download

what's wrong ?

how to click new terms by Google if required, since link missing and new terms are 100-page long, no click

Comment: See: [Google Play Store downloads won't start](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180901/3573) for possible fixes.

Comment: many years ago I was told, Google stores all files for download on array made of Ts of blue ray discs, so download starts when blue ray disk get loaded from changer.

Since I get waiting for download only, no download bar, I assume Google updated terms of service, lacking click button to accept them.
No accept no download.
But how to accept new terms ?
Answer by Google failed to work in my case
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7513003?hl=en&visit_id=637221644453135086-2719153017&rd=1#ts=6241336%2C6241346%2C6241382%2C6241389%2C6241402
"Buy smartphone by Google ;)" to get fix

Comment: @Morrison Chang

turn your comment into answer, since it was you , who guided me to find the right solution.

original answer by #@xavier_fakerat

thank you

Comment: Great that you were able to solve your problem. In future please don't use emoji or smile faces or semi-related stories (blue ray disk??) to try to get your current problem status across as it confuses anyone trying to help you.

Comment: BR Storage is a real thing
--

Such bug should be self-diagnosed by Google Play Store callback by default
______________________
"Blu-Ray in the Data Center? Facebook Creates 1 Petabyte Storage Rack
Facebook has developed a storage system that packs 1 petabyte of data into a single cabinet filled with 10,000 Blu-Ray optical discs. The company sees potential for Blu-Ray to lower the cost of cold data storage.
https://www.datacenterknowledge.com/archives/2014/01/30/blu-ray-data-center-facebook-creates-1-petabyte-storage-rack

Comment: Just another bug.  ___Application phonebook contacts closes every time I try to call a selected contact.

Some time ago worked fine.  -- Not sure what's wrong and how to cure the problem since  Uninstall updates doesn't work for Phonebook Contacts.

Smiles about smartphone by Google is ok, since developer of Android and manufacturer of smartphone, in one-person, runs home tests and can remove such bug on-the-fly

thank you for your comments and time

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

"
Touch Google Play Store > Uninstall updates .
When prompted to change the Play Store app back to the factory version, touch OK.

"
from
[Google Play Store downloads won't start](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180901/google-play-store-downloads-wont-start)

and what follows is:

exactly: 
Accept New Terms
OK

Google updated terms of service by the end of March 2020 but failed to attach 
ACCEPT NEW Terms
OK botton
to 100+ page long document,

so Ms got Google Play store disabled ;)

BTW
I have downloaded and installed
GPS Tools app
for test
but this app is made of commercials only,
no GPS mode ;(
just ads and links to ads

Ask Google
to update answer page
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7513003?hl=en&visit_id=637221644453135086-2719153017&rd=1#ts=6241336%2C6241346%2C6241382%2C6241389%2C6241402

appending the true cause of our problems